# Symfony2 loading Assets for a Logo

Tags: symfony

I am trying to load a Logo in the `base.html.twig`. Actually I think this should be extremely basic and easy. However I want this Asset not to lie in a Bundle but in `app/Resource/`, because as far as I am concerned this should be the right place for App-Wide Resources. However I can't load get it to load or even get copied to the web folder. Am I doing something terrible wrong, because it feels so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files (part of the application and not a specific bundle) belong to the `web` directory as stated in the documentation:

> The web root directory is the home of all public and static files
>   including images, stylesheets, and JavaScript files.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html#the-web-directory

**EDIT**

If you want your js and css to be compressed simply use:

```
{% stylesheets 'public/css/*' filter='yui_cs' %}
      <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

And

```
{% javascripts 'public/js/*' filter='yui_js' %}
      <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

*You may need to change the filter name according to your configuration*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I think this also should be possible using `Assets`. Because I want my js and css get compressed automatically. Described e.g. here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/yuicompressor.html

Comment: I have updated my answer. I know it looks like you could store those files in `app/Resources`, but there is no way (or at least I don't know how...) to dump the assetics when doing this...

Comment: Thank you again, but in which folder, you put the js and css files? In `web/public`? As far as I understand, they get copied and compressed during `assets:install`

Comment: `assets:install` only creates the symlinks to the resources when calling the assetics filers is part of the view layer. It doesn't work when you use the `{% javascripts %}` and `{% stylesheets %}` to compress the files?

Comment: It can create symlinks or copies the files. Well I haven't tried yet. But the compression has to be done once by calling `assets:install` and not everytime somebody visits the Site, this would end in horrible performance. So I am wondering how this will work. And where to put the files. I really can't find this in the documentation.

Comment: To my understanding, the compression is processed by the view layer (twig in this case calling the YUI compressor) and then cached in the `app/cache`.